# Angular Validation: Mat-Error doesn't go away after correcting the input

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-material, datepicker

I have a date-picker implemented which displays a mat-error whenever a date is invalid. The problem is the error doesn't go away when the date has been corrected unless the user clicks on the calendar and then picks the correct date.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance">
  <input
    matInput
    class="om-text-input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY"
    [required]="isRequired"
    [min]="minDate"
    [max]="maxDate"
    (focus)="Datepicker.open()"
    [matDatepicker]="Datepicker"
    #input="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="date"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="Datepicker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #Datepicker>
    <mat-datepicker-actions>
      <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
    </mat-datepicker-actions>
  </mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error class="om-error" *ngIf="input.hasError">Invalid date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

component:

```
 export class DatePickerComponent {
      date: Date = new Date();
      minDate = DateTime.now().minus({ days: 365 }).toISODate();
      maxDate = DateTime.now().plus({ days: 365 }).toISODate();
    
      @Input()
  isRequired = false;

  @Input()
  appearance: Appearance = Appearance.outline;
}
```

Module:

```
providers: [{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'DE-EU' }],
```

[image]

Comment: When select from datepicker, what is the date value format? Is it same as '28.10.2021'?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MatNativeDateModule`, then [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) is used. The format are not configurable. When it fail to parse the text, it set an Invalid Date as the value, thus being invalid.

If you want to support this format, you need to use another [date adapter](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) that support your format. Material ship with `MomentDateModule` that support [custom format](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#momentdatemodule-formats).